# Update multiple rows in MySQL between two Id

Tags: mysql

I'm try to update different rows at one time through a group of names I use the following function:

```
BEGIN

set @id1 := 2591;
set @id2 := 2594;

set @i := @id1;

SET
  @names = 'marwan,wael,adnan,sameh,';

LABEL1: WHILE (Locate(',', @names) > 0) do
SET
  @Name = SUBSTRING(@names, 1, LOCATE(',', @names));

SET @Name = SUBSTRING(@names,1, LOCATE(',', @names)-1);
UPDATE employees SET NAME = @Name
WHERE
  id = @i;

SET
  @i = @i + 1;

END WHILE label1;
end
```

The function works, but the problem is that it only adds the first name and it's repeated in all rows. attached picture:

[image]

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Provide the task, not only the way which you decide to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iterational cycle checks the next condition:

```
WHILE (Locate(',', @names) > 0)
```

But `@names` variable is not altered within the cycle - hence you have infinity loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING(@names, 1, LOCATE(',', @names)-1)
```

The problem is here. Both of your calls to SUBSTRING start with the first character so they always find the first name in the list. You should move the start index further for subsequent calls.

And also the function does not stop because the value of @names never changes. No matter how many times it runs, the following check always returns a value greater than 0.

```
 WHILE (Locate(',', @names) > 0) do
```

You should trim processed names from the variable.

Comment: Hello brother, can you share some codes for the steps to solve the problem according to your understanding of the problem. Thank you